# Facebook graph API 2.0 returns small pictures

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my application I'm query the last feeds of some selected channels.
For the query i'm using the following request(token and app id has been hidden for this post) -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=my_access_token&fields=from,story,picture,link,type,message,object_id&filter=app_id&locale=en_US&limit=20
```

as a results i get a json object that contains all the requested data, BUT, the "picture" url always points to small picture.

How can i change my request to return the large picture?
I have try to add -

```
&type=large
```

But it did not work for me.

Comment: I faced the same with this issue. The previous versions of Facebook Graph API, we can get large picture via 'type=large' parameter

Comment: Hi Phat H. VU, It is still does not work for me. Pictures still small...

Comment: Hi Phat H. VU, What version of Facebook SDK do you run currently? Does it solve the problem?
I'm consider this change in case it solve this problem.

Comment: Hi eyal, I am using Facebook Graph API, I tried a lot of ways but no luck. Please, share your solution if you have, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've only been able to do some very basic testing, but I've got a couple of things you can try.

1. **Separate API call:** 
   The easiest way to accomplish this is to use a link similar to the one you're using for your call.
   `https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=large&access_token=token`
   should get you the proper image.
2. **Nest the request:**
   You can try nesting requests, so-called "field-expansion." The request would go from looking like this: 
   `&fields=from,story,picture,link,` (*snippet of your current request*)
    to resembling something like this: 
   `&fields=from,story,picture.type(large),link,`
    where `picture.type(large)` is the part you'll want to pay attention to.

   You'll find the documentation for nesting requests over here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#fieldexpansion